# How to do text drawing like "layer.masksToBounds = NO" for UILabel?

Tags: ios, uilabel

A `UILabel` layer comes with `masksToBounds` such that drawing can be overflowed outside the label's frame. However the text within the label are always truncated:

[image]

Is it possible to show the truncated parts?

Comment: May be the font size exceeds the size of your label

Comment: Yes, but it's intentional. The text size are shown differently under different font. If I set the size for a particular font, another font will be shown as too small. I'd like to restrict the text appearance by the UILabel frame instead of font size.

Comment: So you can constraint the size of text in UILabel

Answer (score 0):

You can use `boundingRectWithSize:options:context:`

```
CGRect labelRect=[string boundingRectWithSize:CGSizeMake(100, 50) options:NSStringDrawingUsesFontLeading attributes:@{NSFontAttributeName: [UIFont systemFontOfSize:30.0f]} context:nil];

[_label setFrame:labelRect];
```